# View controller will dismiss without any animation when come back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

App on iOS6 and my iPhone is 4S, I present view controller using Storyboard and dismiss with following code:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works fine until my app went to background and then come to foreground again, I present a view controller and dismiss it. The view controller will dismiss without any animation. I know it's a small problem but it did confuse me.

Is that a bug of iOS6 SDK?